# Kendo MVC Grid: Creating a Custom command button and passing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a custom command button to fire a custom delete function. I need to pass the ID of my model to my custom delete function. You'll notice that I'm trying to pass in a static '5' as a test but I would like to pass in the ID of the row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(240);
    columns.Bound(p => p.City).Width(170);
    columns.Bound(p => p.State).Width(170);
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit();
        command.Custom("Delete").Click("PropertyPage.DeleteProperty").HtmlAttributes(new { @Id = 5 });
        }).Width(166);
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("PropertyRead", "Property"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Property"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Property"))
))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should send any Data keys specified:

```
command.Custom("Delete").SendDataKeys(true).Click("PropertyPage.DeleteProperty");
```

DataKeys are specified in the DataSource section:

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))  // THIS IS YOUR DATA KEY
    .Read(read => read.Action("PropertyRead", "Property"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Property"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "Property"))
```

I also found this page on Kendo's site.  It helped me out when I was having a similar issue:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/widgets/grid#editing

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I access that datakey in my function DeleteProperty?

function DeleteProperty(e)...

I tried an alert(e) and all I'm seeing is object. I need to get the Id.

Comment: My mistake.  I didn't realize that this was calling a javascript function.  Sorry!  With that in mind, change your custom command syntax to:
command.Custom("Delete").Click("PropertyPage.DeleteProperty");

And your function should look like this:
function DeleteProperty(e) {  //Or whatever your function name is
 var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
 var id = dataItem.Id;
 alert(id);

}