# Kendo UI Grid custom command

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to setup a button to do a post back to a function using a Kendo UI grid. When I click the button I created it just passes null for the object. Here is what I have for my code...

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelObject>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.id);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("do something").SendDataKeys(true).Click("functionName"); });
    })...
```

and the javascript is...

```
function functionName(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data: { item: e },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) { }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question should hopefully answer your question

[Kendo MVC Grid: Creating a Custom command button and passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368269/kendo-mvc-grid-creating-a-custom-command-button-and-passing-parameters)

Look at the comments for the javascript solution.

If you are still having problems. Let me know as I have a possible solution but it depends on what you are expecting to send back to the server as your object.